# What is the adjective for someone with cancer?

Tags: word-request

What is the adjective for a person that has cancer? For example, cancerous individual, cancerous child, or something else?

Comment: A *cancered* individual is someone affected by *cancerous* growth.

Comment: "A cancer patient" is a widely-used phrase. I don't recall any adjective used before "individual" to indicate his or her cancer patient status.

Comment: cancer stricken

Comment: We don't say *cancered*.  We usually use multiple words rather than any single adjective.

Comment: It may not be the preferred use, but it exists and is used nonetheless. And it is the only single-word adjective that exists along with cancerous. I get where you're coming from though and I agree it's not the most mellifluous way of saying it. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cancered

Comment: cancer sufferer

Comment: For those being overly PC, how about "carcinogenically challenged"?

Comment: You could call them "crabby", but only the well read would get it.

Comment: @TheNate - The odds of anyone getting that are astronomical.

Comment: "afflicted with cancer" is common, and after cancer as a subject is brought into context, "afflicted individuals" is often used.

Comment: Sadly, the best would be Unlucky.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The adjective [*cancerous*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cancerous) usually modifies cells, growth, tumor, etc.

It is better to use a prepositional phrase *with cancer* which post-modifies the noun.

> A person (diagnosed) **with cancer**

Or you could use **cancer patient** which means:

> a person who is receiving medical treatment for a malignant growth or
>   tumour: '*an increase in the number of cancer patients*'

[[Collins Online Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cancer-patient)]

Comment: Indeed, if you called a person cancerous, they'd probably be a little insulted regardless of their medical condition. (They'd probably be more forgiving to someone learning the language, but still...)

Comment: The important word is *diagnosed*, and the most common idiom IMO: *diagnosed with cancer*.

Answer (score 30):

We never use the adjective *cancerous* to refer to a person suffering from cancer. If you do so, you may cause people great offense as well as emotional pain.

If you wish to refer to people who have cancer, you can refer to them as *cancer patients*, as noted in another answer here. You can also refer to people with cancer as *cancer sufferers* or *people with cancer*.

---

<sup>**Usage note:**</sup>

<sup>One reason that you might offend them is because "cancerous person" is often used metaphorically to describe a person regularly causing negative effects to others around them i.e. that person is a *metaphorical* cancer.</sup>

Comment: Also it is the **growth itself** that is *cancerous*. Calling the patient cancerous implies that they **are** a cancer rather than they **have** a cancerous growth.

Comment: +1. The phrase *cancer survivor* is also quite common, though it also includes people who no longer have cancer (and, in general, has many competing definitions).

Answer (score 2):

In English it is common to use the term "cancer patient" as stated already.
The following is not a real answer, as much as a suggestion: in Greek, someone suffering from cancer is called carcinopathés (noun, a person suffering from cancer). I think the addition of a term such as carcinopath or canceropath in the English vocabulary wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 2):

Single words (if hyphenated counts as single word) would be "cancer-ridden" or "cancer-stricken".

Comment: -Laden, -victim, -patient...

Comment: "Cancer-ridden" goes beyond suggesting that they are a cancer patient, it implies a pretty bad case.

Comment: And, to add to @nnnnnn's comment, "cancer-ridden" has a negative connotation that may well cause offence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word adjective you can come up with that won't range from being offensive, to extremely offensive and whose use won't mark you as a weirdo with no social sense.

Nevertheless, if my life somehow depended on coming up with one, I would make my answer "becancered", taking advantage of the "be-" morphological formation to denote "afflicted with", "surrounded with", "loaded with", "stricken" and such.

Somehow it has a small softening effect, placing a separation between the subject and the disease. There is a certain slight nuance in "cancered" in that to be "cancered" is in some sense, to be identified as being one with the cancer, to be inseparable from it, or the degradation of health which the progression of cancer causes. The "be-" prefix re-frames the cancer as some external affliction which in some metaphoric sense drapes the individual and can be shed, or something that the subject has (like a "bespectacled" person is someone who is wearing glasses, and something "bejeweled" is covered with jewels).

This possibly may have to do with "be + *word* + ed" plausibly deriving from a noun sense of *word*. In "becancered", "cancer" refers to the noun "cancer", and not to cancer as a verb, unlike in "cancered", where the derivation is ambiguous; there is a verb sense which means "degraded by the progressive action of cancer" and not simply "having cancer".

Answer (score 1):

Most sources I can find online tell me "cancerous" is grammatically correct for both a growth and a person, as meaning "relating to or affected with cancer".

Though if I may, I find this expression **very** repulsive. It might be because I played online games too much, but I think that referring to a "patient with cancer" or a "cancer patient" sounds way better than a "cancerous/cancered(?) patient".

Comment: When used to describe a person, *cancerous* is (in my experience) a metaphorical description of the negative effect they have on the people around them. I've never heard it used to describe a cancer patient.

Comment: Quite a few dictionaries cite _cancerous_ as meaning "relating to or affected with cancer". In this case, it makes grammatical sense to describe a cancer patient as cancerous. Though I agree with you on the fact that I've never, nor will I ever hear someone talk about a _cancerous patient_ in a serious talk. It's more grammatically correct than "okay to use" indeed, editing.

Comment: The OP is not asking for a grammatically correct phrase  but for an appropriate expression. *"Canceriferous Human"* and *cancer carrying individual* are grammatically correct, but not used–and *cancerous person* does not refer to a person who has the disease cancer.

Answer (score 1):

Cancer-stricken

Examples:

[Cancer-Stricken Farmers Sue Monsanto Over Roundup](http://www.newser.com/story/225150/cancer-stricken-farmers-sue-monsanto-over-roundup.html)

[Amanda Ferreira, the cancer-stricken Auckland mother who fought for more time with her girls](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11645817)